# Connecting database to program in local network

Tags: c++, qt, ms-access, database-connection

I'm trying to connect a Qt program to a database existing in another computer.

I'm using Ms Access database and i already had it connected to my programme in the same computer ( with the QODBC driver) as below:

```
db1 =  QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db1.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};FIL={MS Access};DBQ=BDProjet.mdb");
```

now i'm trying to extend my programme to be a localnetwork programme so i need to connect  my programme to the same database from another computer, so for testing it i'm using the loopback adresse (127.0.0.1) , i've already tried this but it's not working:

```
db1 =  QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db1.setHostName("localhost");
db1.setPort(3306);
db1.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};FIL={MS Access};DBQ=j\\BDProjet.mdb");
```

How i'm supposed to connect my database?

Comment: up no one?? please help

Comment: Why are you using localhost and 127.0.01 if you are connecting from another computer? You need to set computer name as host name I think

Comment: If "j\\BDProjet.mdb" is your network path, try remove setHostName and setPort lines (comment them)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding;

```
  if(!db1.open())
  {
    // aaaargh!
    qDebug() << db1.lastError();
  }
  else
  {
     // your database commands here
  }
```

after the code that you have.